# In parallel execution how to fetch different transaction IDs from the application opened in chrome browser--Selenium Java

Tags: thread-local, selenium-java

My scenario is for example in my parallel execution for 2 scenarios the application is launched in two chrome browser and two transactions are initiated. I need the the 2 transaction for which I used "transaction.getAttribute("value")" because the transaction IDs can be seen when I do inspect.
I wrote the below code but only one transaction ID is getting fetched. I am using ThreadLocal for parallel execution. I checked there are two different thread got assigned for two test.

List AlltransactionID = DriverManager.getDriver().findElements(By.id("transaction-id"));

```
    int i = AlltransactionID.size();     // (here I am getting size=1)
    log.info("Total number of Transaction ID " + i);
    for(WebElement tranID : AlltransactionID){
        Object transactionID = tranID.getAttribute("value");
        log.info("Value is --> " + transactionID);
    }
```

Note: I have used driver.findelements because I want to fetch the transactions IDs from the two test. Please assist

Comment: Here, I am getting -                                                                                     
      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)

Comment: The 2 test cases are different, right? So, did you try having a static List variable to store both the transaction ids?